# Parse Server: logging specific functions

Tags: parse-server

Is there a way to turn off logging on a specific cloud function but not for all of them? My issue is that the result of my cloud function contains a base64 image, and Parse Server by default output the base64 string to the log, which makes my daily log files extremely large and hard to maintain.

setting logLevel = 'warn' instead of 'info' solves this problem but then I lost the I/O information of other cloud functions which I also need..

thanks.

Comment: Could you creat your own separate log for your cloud functions with just the information you need?

Comment: thanks buckettt. I ended up with setting logLevel = 'warn' and manually console.log(request.params) for some cloud functions.

Answer (score 0):

Can you open an issue in the repo with the specifics about your use case? We'll be probably able to slim down the logging for long base64 strings

Comment: issue opened. https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/issues/3918

Comment: Awesome! Thanks!